# Hackerrank Frequency Queries

Tags: python

You are given queries. Each query is of the form two integers described below:

1. Insert x in your data structure.
2. Delete one occurrence of y from your data structure, if present.
3. Check if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly. If yes, print 1 else 0.

Example input :

`queries = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2)]`

The problem is pretty self-explanatory and I think I have a decent solution:

loop through the queries and increment and decrement the frequencies of each number accordingly in a dict
... simultaneously in a separate dict keep track of how many times each key of the other dict appears

when checking if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly y for QUERY 3 you would check if the count of y in the second dict exists...

I am passing most test cases but failing some.. can anyone explain flaws in my thinking.

```
def freqQuery(queries):
    frequency = {}
    results = []
    frequencyValues = {}
    for query in queries:
        q = query[0]
        val = query[1]
        if q == 1:
            frequency[val] = frequency.get(val, 0) + 1
            freq = frequency[val]
            frequencyValues[freq] = frequencyValues.get(freq, 0) + 1
            frequencyValues[freq-1] = frequencyValues.get(freq-1, 1) - 1
        elif q == 2:
            if val in frequency.keys():
                frequency[val] += - 1
                if frequency[val] < 0:
                    frequency[val] = 0
                freq = frequency[val]
                frequencyValues[freq + 1] = frequencyValues.get(freq + 1, 1) - 1
                frequencyValues[freq] = frequencyValues.get(freq, 1) + 1
        elif q == 3:
            if val in frequencyValues.keys():
                if frequencyValues[val] > 0:
                    results.append(1)
                else:
                    results.append(0)
            else:
                results.append(0)
            

    return results
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# --stackoverflow help fixing op code

# minor code refactor and your code passes all the test cases.

    elif q == 2:
        if val in frequency:

            freq = frequency[val]
            frequencyValues[freq] = frequencyValues.get(freq, 1) - 1

            frequency[val] += - 1 # <---- decrement line
            frequencyValues[freq-1] = frequencyValues.get(freq-1, 1) + 1

            #-------------------- 
            if frequency[val] < 0:
                frequency[val] = 0
            #--------------------

            # this condition should have been checked at the end as after decrement line ( frequency[val] -= 1 ) value of frequency[val] can get negative

            # also frequency[val] += - 1 ---> can be better written as frequency[val] -= 1
```

**my solution all tc accepted**

```
from collections import defaultdict
n = int(input())

a = defaultdict(int) # num:cnt
b = defaultdict(int) # cnt: how many nums have this cnt

for tc in range(n):
    op, data = map(int, input().strip().split())

    if op == 1:
        # insert
        b[a[data]] -= 1
        a[data]+=1
        b[a[data]] += 1

    elif op == 2:
        # delete
        if data in a:
            b[a[data]] -= 1
            a[data] -= 1
            b[a[data]] += 1

        a[data]  = 0 if a[data] < 0 else a[data]

    else:
        # check if any key in b = data and has count > 0         
        print('1' if data in b and b[data] > 0  else '0')
```

**first approach but I was getting timeout in 4 test cases**

```
from collections import defaultdict
n = int(input())

data_freq_dict = defaultdict(int)

for tc in range(n):
    op, data = map(int, input().strip().split())

    if op == 1:
        # insert
        data_freq_dict[data]+=1

    elif op == 2:
        # delete
        if data in data_freq_dict:
            data_freq_dict[data] -= 1

        data_freq_dict[data]  = 0 if data_freq_dict[data] < 0 else data_freq_dict[data]

    else:
        # check if any key in data_freq_dict has count = data         
        print('1' if data in set(data_freq_dict.values()) else '0')
```

Comment: thank you so much - I knew it was an issue with that dict I just couldn't find why with any reasonable size test case

Answer (score 1):

```py
def freqQuery(queries):
    arr={}
    res=[]
    for i,j in queries:
        if i==1:
            if j in arr:
                arr[j]+=1
            else:
                arr[j]=1
        elif i==2:
            if j in arr:
                if arr[j]>0:
                    arr[j]-=1
        elif i==3:
            if j in arr.values():
                res.append(1)
            else:
                res.append(0)
    return res
```

Only one testcase will fail in python3 compiler due to timeout
SO I ran it in pypy3 which compiles faster than python3...

Note: here only one dict is used. I think in the optimal solution 2 dicts are used.